# Kinetic Shift of Simple Cleavage

Tags: kinetics, ions, mass-spectrometry

What is the kinetic shift for the simple cleavage fragmentation if the ion source residence time is 100 microseconds, the time to reach the detector after leaving the ion source is 10 microseconds? (given that the simple cleavage is the green line below)

[image]

My work: Because kinetic shift is Ef-E0, E0 would be the energy at which the ion is in the ion source, or where the green line and 4 (from 100 microseconds, or 10^-4) intersect. Then Ef would be where the green line and 5 (from 10 microseconds, or 10^-5) intersect. Does this seem correct?